# Can't get the id in play framework scala program

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

Here is my view page and here not get the id..

```
@(userprofiles: List[UserProfile], myFriend: models.MyFriend, userprofile: models.UserProfile)
@helper.form(action = routes.Application.listMyFriend) {
```

Value id is not a member of `List[models.UserProfile]`

Here is where the error occurred:

```
    @for(userprofile <- userprofiles.id) {
        @if(userprofile.id == userprofiles) {
        } else {
            <img src="@routes.Assets.at("images/img2.png")" width="200" height="200" />
            <br><h5>@userprofile.name</h5>
            <h6>@userprofile.gender</h6>
            <h6>@userprofile.date_of_birth</h6>
            <div class="actions">


            <input type="submit" class="btn primary" value="+1 Add As Friend" title="Send Friend Request"></div>
            <br/>
        }
    }
}
```

This is method in application

```
def listMyFriend = Action { implicit request =>
    if (request.session.get("myFriendId") == None) {
        Results.Redirect("/")
    } else {
        val userprofiles: UserProfile = null
        val userprofileId = request.session.get("userId").get.toLong // userProfileId
        val userprofile = UserProfile.findUserByAccountId(userprofileId).get

        println(userprofile)
        myFriendForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
            errors => BadRequest(views.html.myFriend(errors, userprofile, myfriend, myfrnd)),
            myFriend => {
                println("errors")
                val myFriendOpt = UserProfile.myFriend(userprofile.id.get)
                println(myFriendOpt)

                myFriendOpt match {
                    case None =>
                }

                Results.Redirect("/myFriend")
            }
        )
    }
}
```

And this is Routes:

```
POST /createMyFriend    controllers.Application.listMyFriend
GET  /allFriends        controllers.Application.listAllFriends(userId:Long)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message tells you what is wrong. Your `userprofiles` is a list of `UserProfile`. It does not have a member called `id`. Yet, you are trying to access it:

```
@for(userprofile <- userprofiles.id)
//                              ^--- this is invalid
```

I think what you are trying to do is:

```
@for(up <- userprofiles){
  @if(up.id == userprofile.id) {} else { ... }
}
```

Comment: i change that into  but the id's are get but the if statement get wrong

@for(userprofile <- userprofiles){
@if(userprofile.useraccountid != useraccount.id) {